# Editting XML files better than Regex

Tags: xml, xml-editor

I'm using Jetbrains Idea as my main XML editor, i also have some expirience in Eclipse, as i'm game-designer and not a programmer i mostly use Regex to edit complex xml configuration files of games. But sometimes this is not enough, so i wonder with what i can edit XML files more efficiently?

Here is an example which is needed to be solved:

Example 1:
We have 2 xml files - monsters.xml and levels.xml, in monsters.xml each monster has an attribute atkPower="x", what i need is to split this attribute into 2 and copy into the specific levels.xml node to make them minatkPower="x-10" maxatkPower="x+10".

Maybe some easy to start script languages? Or maybe some specific xml\text editors?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth learning XSLT and/or XQuery, which can often solve such problems in a few lines of code. There's a learning curve, just as there is for regular expressions, but they are the right tools for the job.